# Unable to select item in android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked

Tags: android, listview

I am using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked` for a `listview` in my application. but i'm unable to select a list item as checked.

here is the code

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Selectfarmer.this,    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,arraylistfarmer);
    lvselectfarmer.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
```

Comment: have you used the setOnItemClickListener??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found it, you need to use

```
lvselectfarmer.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,arraylistfarmer);
lvselectfarmer.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
int len = lvselectfarmer.getCount();
SparseBooleanArray checked = lvselectfarmer.getCheckedItemPositions();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
 if (checked.get(i)) {
  String item = lvselectfarmer.get(i);
  /* do whatever you want with the checked item */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    CheckedTextView textview = (CheckedTextView)v;
    textview.setChecked(!textview.isChecked());
}
```